# Spring autowiring not working with lazy-init

Tags: java, spring, autowired, sessionfactory

I am trying to autowire my sessionFactory bean with Spring when I kick off an integration test.  As I am creating a new instance of a service class in my test, I believe I need to lazy-init. For the life of me I have no idea why my sessionFactory continues to be null. Please help!

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

MyServiceImpl.java

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
    return new HibernateTemplate(this.sessionFactory);
}
```

Test.java

```
public void test() {
    MyServiceImpl impl = (MyServiceImpl) Class.forName("foo.package.MyServiceImpl").newInstance();
    HibernateTemplate template = impl.getHibernateTemplate();
}
```

My "template" variable in the test is always null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing the MyServiceImpl yourself, which means it's not managed by spring, so spring doesn't process your Autowired annotation.  You need to get the MyServiceImpl from the spring context.

Comment: Thanks mate.  Theoretically, if I leave the test "as is", am I able to inject dependencies via Spring in any way?  Or will I manually need to set up a connection to my DB in my service implementation? (in which case scrapping Spring's DI altogether)

Comment: Generally, if you want to test the bean outside of spring, or if you want to be able to mock different dependencies that would normally be injected, you would set them up with constructor or setter injection so you can manually construct it and set it to whatever value you need.

Comment: What is your test trying to assert?

Comment: This is just sample code, this is not my complete test nor complete context and impl.